# Adapt a Card height according to content in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a **Card**, consisting of a title, a description and an iconbutton bar at the bottom .

**Only the description has a variable size.**

I want that when my card is created **it adapts its height**

**Here the widget for the description :**

```
///Widget for the description of the post
  Widget _descriptionPost()
  {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 7, top: 10),
      child: Text(
        widget.postModel.descriptionPost,
        maxLines: 4,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Here's the build :**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.2,
      height: HERE I WANT ADAPT THE HEIGHT,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5, top: 5, bottom: 5),
      child: Card(
        elevation: 3,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: ()
          {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/post_detail', arguments: widget.postModel);
          },
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              _profilePicAndUsernameAndTime(),
              _titlePostAndNameGame(),
              _descriptionPost(),
              Spacer(),
              _bottomBar()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `constraints` property of your `Container` and set it accordingly to your needs.

```
constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 200.0)
```

This will ensure that your `Container` will have any H value between `0` and `200.0`, based on its `child`.

However, have in mind, that if the `child` needs more height than your `maxHeight`, you'll experience an overflow, so you should only use this if you have a maximum height as requisite, otherwise just leave it blank.

Comment: This doesn't actually work. It is only how it would be expected to work. In practice, it will always be the `maxHeight`, disregarding the child's height. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73343559/3935156). Note that this video makes it seem like it will only respect either max or min but not both - which is also how I have experienced it works.